# Separate projects and make one way directional features sharing

Tags: git, gitlab

As I am new to Git, i need some advise with this. I have a main project that is runnable on its own and inside it there is a folder that is considered as a sub-project. I can run and have a separate executable for each.

I did my search and only found this answer,
[Git - 2 projects sharing features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760108/git-2-projects-sharing-features)
But I already decided to go with separate projects and the only solution given close to that is to have a common library which is not my problem.

**What I want is the following**,

- Separate the sub project to have its own project (*subproject 2*)
- Any new features in that *subproject 1* (in the main project) to be
  included in the separate created new project (*subproject 2*)
- Any edit in that *subproject 2* not to be included in the *subproject 1*

[image]

Is that possible and if so how it could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible avenue would be to declare the `project1` repository as [a submodule of `project2`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

That means:

- `project1` no longer has a `project2` subfolder (and ignore project2 existence)
- `project2` has a `project1` subfolder, which helps `project2` to build itself, picking from the `project1` subfolder the features it needs.
- Any edit in that `project2` will not to be included in project1